# Cannot update item where two columns combination must be unique

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am making an application with azure mobile services which stores users hours and points in a table called attended users. The problem I have is when I try and update the one specific user it selects all of the users with the same club id. I need an update function that finds a user with a club id and UniqueUserID that are unique, then updates the hours and points based on the one result.

Controller Code

```
$scope.saveChanges = function(){
$scope.show($ionicLoading);
var query = client.getTable('AttendedClubs').update({id: clubID.getJson(), UniqueUserID: memberID.getJson(), Hours: $scope.profile.Hours, Points: $scope.profile.Points}).done(function(results) {


        $scope.hide($ionicLoading);





    }, function(error) {


        $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
        alertDialogue.pop("No Internet Connection","Check Connection");
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a unique ID of the clubID.  You need to construct this.  When you create your object, do something like:

```
var table = client.getTable('AttendedClubs');
table.insert({
    id: uuid.v4(),
    clubID: clubID.getJson(),
    UniqueUserID: memberID
    ...
});
```

To update all records, first do a fetch, then do an update on a per-record basis.  Use the id to uniquely identify the record.

Comment: So I must make a random unique id to update each of my records? This seems like an inefficient way but I understand.

Comment: Each record must have a unique ID.  According to your spec, neither your clubID nor the userID is unique within the table.  So, use something else.